# submit a form using javascript on click

Tags: javascript, html

I am just a newbie in html and javascript. 
I have a form like this

```
<form id="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/test" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
    <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9">
    <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want that when the button is clicked then the value will be submitted for that button. Lets say I have clicked on 3rd button and you can see in the last button the value is 9. so I want to submit the value 9. So can someone kindly tell me how to to do this?
I have more then 10 buttons like this inside the form. I have just used 3 here

Comment: Just using three forms seems easier ?

Answer (score 0):

All the values in the form will be submitted, give id, so that you can take the values using those id's

```
request.getparameter("idname"); // if you are using java

<form id="add-to-cart" action="http://example.com/test" method="post">
   <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" **id="cartkeyid1"** value="1">
      <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" **id="cartkeyid2"** value="3">
      <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" **id="cartkeyid3"** value="9">
      <a href="#" onclick="" class="try-now-button">add to cart</a>
   </div>
</form>
```

This way you will be able to get the values you required.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could make each item it's own `<form>` and use `<button type="submit">` within them o create individual posts:

```
<div>
  <form action="http://example.com/test" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <button type="submit" class="try-now-button">add to cart</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="http://example.com/test" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3">
    <button type="submit" class="try-now-button">add to cart</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form action="http://example.com/test" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cartkey" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="9">
    <button type="submit" class="try-now-button">add to cart</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you could take the javascript approach with jQuery

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  var postItem = function (item) {
    $.post('http://example.com/test', item, function (data) {
      alert('Response: ' + data);
    });
  }
</script>
<div>
  <button class="try-now-button" onclick="postItem({ cartkey: '', id: 1 })">
    add to cart
  </button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="try-now-button" onclick="postItem({ cartkey: '', id: 3 })">
    add to cart
  </button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="try-now-button" onclick="postItem({ cartkey: '', id: 3 })">
    add to cart
  </button>
</div>
```